# How to run Firefox inside wine with windows compatible plugins?

Tags: wine

how to run firefox inside wine with windows compatible plugins..i am a newbie..i have to complete a online training program and need adobe flashplayer plugin.

it seems it is not available for linux..so what should i do here ? how can wine help?
please tell me in baby steps..thanks

amith

Comment: you don't need wine to install flash on firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

It will ask for your password.

Restart firefox afterwards. (Firefox is installed by default).

Answer (score 0):

Flash player is available for Linux.
Honestly I'm a bit confused by your question, but, here is a link to help you out:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash

Answer (score 0):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) is a great application for managing Wine and installing Windows programs on Linux. There's an Ubuntu package on the website, so it's easy to install.

After downloading and installing the program, you can launch it by going to **Applications > Games > PlayOnLinux**.
Follow the prompts to install Firefox for Windows and the application will also install Flash for Windows.

Comment: He doesn't need flash for windows to access flash applications and sites.